# SQL Phrasing Issues

Tags: sql, sas

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, 
              AND, AS, BETWEEN, CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, FORMAT, FROM, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, INFORMAT, INTO, IS, LABEL, LE, LEN, LENGTH, 
              LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, TRANSCODE, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_VVW_DWH_PTN AS 
   SELECT t1.PlayerId, 
          t1.FirstName, 
          t1.LastName, 
          t1.Email, 
          t2.EndDate, 
          t2.Most_Recent_Overall_Experience, 
          t1.AdtLifetimeRange AS AdtLifetimeRange1,
          (SELECT t1.AdtLifetimeRange WHERE [t2.EndDate] <= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS ADT6MoBack,
          (SELECT t1.AdtLifetimeRange WHERE [t2.EndDate] >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)) AS ADT6MoForAS,
 
      FROM TDQT.vCXSurvey t2
           INNER JOIN TDQT.vCXPlayer_SAS t1 ON (t2.PlayerId = t1.PlayerId);
    WHERE t2.EndDate <'03/20/2022'
QUIT;
```

```
                                      76
```

I haven't been able to find the issue to fix.

Comment: usually a comma after the last time in the select list is a syntax error in sql -- `AS ADT6MoForAS,` and also you have a semi-colon after the inner join before the where, which is another problem. Really you should be testing this select before turning it into a proc.

Comment: You don't have valid SAS SQL, is that T or Oracle SQL? `[t2.EndDate] <= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)` and `WHERE t2.EndDate <'03/20/2022'` are two places where errors are occuring.

Comment: Please also post more of the log, it highlights where in the code the issue may be occurring.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove square brackets ]
- Use [INTNX()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) for date increments
- Dates need to be in [date. style](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/lrcon/9.4/p0cq7f0icfjr8vn19vyunwmmsl7m.htm#n1bbnuc86c5c5hn113qbpt5u9g5f) - DDMMMYY ("20MAR2022"d)
- There is no NOW() function in SAS, but there is [TODAY()](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0hm9egy8s7mokn1mz0yxng80ax5.htm) which returns today's date
- Missing semicolon at end of query (before QUIT;)

An attempt at correcting your code, but not 100% sure as I don't know what type of SQL you're using:

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_VVW_DWH_PTN AS 
   SELECT t1.PlayerId, 
          t1.FirstName, 
          t1.LastName, 
          t1.Email, 
          t2.EndDate, 
          t2.Most_Recent_Overall_Experience, 
          t1.AdtLifetimeRange AS AdtLifetimeRange1,
          (SELECT t1.AdtLifetimeRange WHERE t2.EndDate <= intnx('month', today(), -6, 'e')) AS ADT6MoBack,
          (SELECT t1.AdtLifetimeRange WHERE t2.EndDate >= intnx('month', today(), -6, 'e')) AS ADT6MoForAS,
 
      FROM TDQT.vCXSurvey t2
           INNER JOIN TDQT.vCXPlayer_SAS t1 ON (t2.PlayerId = t1.PlayerId);
    WHERE t2.EndDate <'20Mar2022'd;
QUIT;
```

Comment: You missed the extra comma after the last column.  Most likely because the commas are typed at the end of the line instead of at the beginning of the line where a human can scan for them more easily.  Also the extra semicolon for the same reason.